# Can we do a mass update on old wizards links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, dungeons-and-dragons

The link structure in the wizards site has changed.

It has gone from

> ```
> http://dnd.wizards.com/go/we/20060327a
> ```

too

> ```
> http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060327a
> ```

There are dozens of broken links in our site right now. Can we get someone at the StackExchange team to cast *Database Regex Fixup* and mend them?

Comment: Related: [How can I continue to access Wizards of the Coast's D&D 3.5 Web articles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45357/how-can-i-continue-to-access-wizards-of-the-coasts-dd-3-5-web-articles)

Comment: Note that, in many cases, this won't actually mend them - a lot of stuff is gone, not just restructured.

Comment: In many cases it won't, but in many cases it will.  The real questions are "how much effort for how many fixes?" and "will it break any links that *were* working?"

Comment: Anyone asked Wizards to update their url rewrite to handle this?

Answer (score 18):

Five years later, and even the archive.wizards.com links are down. I've searched high and low for the content, but it's nowhere to be found (at least not in official places). This mostly affects Dungeons & Dragons material; some Magic: The Gathering articles like http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/mm/259 are now hosted here: https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/twenty-things-were-going-kill-magic-2013-08-05).

I've set up a script which examines posts for these URLs, checks the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) for the latest snapshot and making an edit (on average one per day, in order to avoid flooding the homepage) if it was archived.

Comment: Thank you for assembling this script. The way Wizards manages old content is pretty disappointing. 

Comment: +1 Epic-level algorithmancy spell. Also, the necromancy of the old meta post.

Comment: @doppelgreener for WotC, there never was a 4th edition. apparently

Comment: You could do once per day and no one would get upset tbh.

Comment: Is it possible to have your script prioritize *open* questions?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov it shouldn't be too hard to make it skip closed questions (and answers to them) for now, and repair those later. OTOH, I don't know how much that would speed up the progress?

Comment: I just think there more value in fixing open questions than closed.

Comment: Can you have the script check for other posts on a Q&A that should be updated whenever it hits one? It seems the answers on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48432/62294) were update a few days apart, I think it would be ideal to tidy up all the posts of a Q&A at the same time.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov actually, that functionality is already present. I have no idea why it didn't work this time, but I will have a look. Thanks for the ping!

Comment: If you can, I would support even one edit every 12 hours due to the sheer amount of links that need updating