# Closing really old questions that have recently been bumped?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

So, recently [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72067/how-does-firesnake-work-raw-rai-or-house-rules) came to the front in the context of [updating broken links](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7529/can-we-do-a-mass-update-on-old-wizards-links). I added some more tags because I felt that the ones already there didn't really cover the question. Then someone voted to close the question as being too unfocused. I agreed with the initiator of the close voting and voted the same.

The thing is, although I had had a look at the question, voting to close had never occured to me. So my question is: If old questions (this one is 7 years old) come to the front, **should I look at them from this perspective and vote to close if something jumps out?** That was definitely the case for this question.

[This discussion about close/reopen requests for old, *inactive* questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/necro-closing-spam) is related, though I am not asking about digging stuff up. Rather I am wondering if I should be vigilant for old questions that might not fit current standards.

Answer (score 16):

Copying part of my answer to the related question you linked: [Necro-Closing Spam](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11704/necro-closing-spam)

#### Off topic questions should be closed, regardless of age. This is consistent with local and network meta guidance.

Doppelgreener writes in her answer [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5987/62294):

> close voting has nothing to do with a question's age, score, or answers. If it's close-worthy by our current standards, we close it, that's it. Sometimes answers help us recognise a question is good & worth keeping open, or not, but that's about it.

Mxyzplk writes in their answer [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1173/62294)

> A bad question, old or not, CW or not, should be closed. But the close should be like any other close - we should be seeing if something can be salvaged out of it.

AceCalhoon writes in their answer  [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1172/62294):

> If you do find an old post and want to do something about it, you have several tools at your disposal. Flagging it, with an explanation as to why it should be closed let's us know your thought. You can also vote to close yourself, although you'll probably need to do some work in meta and chat to get others to look at it within the window.

Doppelgreener returns with more guidance [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6234/62294):

> There were game-recs and other old questions there, and I didn't dump them in from search. I'll get back to that.
>
> If you find it so annoying to deal with, I encourage you to leave the review queue alone at those times. There's plenty of other people to cover for you. If you feel you're being hasty (as in, making poor reviews), please step back from the reviews and get a drink and do something more personally important to you. You avoiding review fatigue is important, the site getting good reviews is important, so it's a win/win if you step back when the review queue's fatiguing you.
>
> I agree there's no urgency in closing them. There is, however, importance in curating our site, and because our questions are timeless we can do that basically whenever. If we only leave curation 'til it's urgent, I can't imagine what condition our site would be in — it'd probably be a cesspool by then and you and I would be long gone. So, yeah, it's not urgent, but that doesn't matter or suggest we shouldn't be closing them.

To the [same question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6233/62294), SSD provides  more guidance:

> Reviewers can just take bites out of it, and bow out when decision fatigue rears its head. Pressing <kbd>Skip</kbd> when at all unsure helps a lot in that regard, too. Others will pick it up and take care of a few more, until the whole queue has been reviewed. Crowdsourcing at work!
>
> It's much preferable for the queue to balloon occasionally, and be handled by the normal crowdsourcing mechanisms it has for precisely such events, than for people to *refrain* from flagging when they see something that deserves a flag. All that refraining results in is different people having to—redundantly—each stop and ponder how much flagging is “too much,” wasting user energy that would be better spent just about anywhere else on-site or off, just so that we can, inexplicably, prevent the flood-management measures designed into the system already from needing to be used.
>
> Clearing each flood with meta (and then spinning off metas that seek to define what is and isn't a flood!) would be, for similar reasons, far more wasteful and inefficient than just using flags and the review queues as they are designed to be used.

Meta.se guidance echoes this guidance [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194117/674198):

> View all question with today's standards. If the question fits as per current standards then leave it open; if it doesn't fit then vote/flag to close it. If we keep the questions which don't fit as per current standards, then people will ask why the questions are still open.

This sentiment of closing old, off topic questions is represented further in these questions from Meta.se:

- [Is flagging to close old questions best practice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123455/674198)
- [How to get attention required to close old posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27007/674198)

The testimony of both site-specific guidance and network meta guidance is overwhelmingly consistent: off topic questions should be closed without regard for age.

Comment: Great explanation of why some questions should be closed, regardless of age.  Would you care to elaborate on situations in which old questions should not be closed?  For example: [Please stop wrongfully closing old, good Q&As](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11413/23547), [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)